# Utilizar parâmetro passado em função dentro do map()

Tags: javascript

Minha função:

```
nameById (url, list, getter = "name") {
    let name = '';
    let id = url.split('/').reverse()[1];
    list.map( user => user.id == id ? name = user.name : null); // name = user.getter
    return name;
},
```

Existe alguma forma de usar esse parâmetro getter dentro do map ?
Dessa forma eu poderia usar essa função não só para buscar por "name" mas por qualquer outra key.

```
nameById('http://localhost:8000/scrum-list/sprint-list/7/', sprintList, 'code') // O retorno seria a propriedade de code e não name
```

Comment: Tente dessa forma `list.map( user => user.id == id ? name = user[getter] : null);`

Comment: Funcionou, vlw!!! Não sabia que era possível fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao passar uma variavel para selecionar uma propriedade em um objeto, use `obj[variavel]`. Considerando o seguindo objeto:

```
obj = {
    nome: 'Lucas',
    idade: 24
}
```

Se utilizarmos a seguinte função:

```
function a(key = "nome"){
    console.log(obj.key)
}
```

Não irá funcionar, porque assim estamos buscando por uma propriedade chamada *key* especificamente, e não o **conteúdo** da variavel *key*. Para isso podemos fazer:

```
function a(key = "nome"){
    // isso é mesmo que obj.nome
    console.log(obj[key]); // irá olhar para o conteúdo de key, nesse caso "nome"
}
```